# Get definition and examples of word from Google translate?

Tags: api, translation, google-translate

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543979/1043882) of [Alternative to Google Translate API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api) that describes how we can translate list of words by inserting them in 'Google spreadsheet'.But how I can get definition or examples of a word?For example when you try to translate "difficult" by "Google Translate" you can see more details in left bottom corner of translete page.

Comment: I have exact the same problem to find words english definition i.e. with google translate, did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, google translate API does not provide more detail except the translated text.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text